# WCF reliable session faults regardless of configured timeouts

Tags: wcf, timeout, channel, fault, reliablesession

I'm trying to use a WCF reliable session to enable callbacks from the service to the client. This callback channel needs to be open indefinitely.

There seems to be a bug in some .NET versions that lets [reliable sessions fault prematurely](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/pauloreichert/archive/2007/02/22/WCF-Reliable-Sessions-Puzzle.aspx). Should be no problem, just set the inactivityTimeout and receiveTimeout to values that are high enough (e.g. `TimeSpan.MaxValue`).

But no matter how I configure my client and services, the channel still faults after 10 minutes, regardless of the value I set as timeout.

This question would be incomplete without my config, so here it goes:

```
<!-- service's app.config -->
<!-- irrelevant stuff snipped .. -->
</binding>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <!-- enable reliable sessions, set timeouts to their maximum possible value!!! -->
    <binding name="netTcpReliable" receiveTimeout="infinite">
      <reliableSession enabled="true" inactivityTimeout="infinite"/>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</binding>

<services>
  <service name="SomeService" behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:port/SomeService"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint name="SomeService_BasicTcpEndpoint"
              address="service"
              binding="netTcpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="netTcpReliable"
              contract="ISomeService" />
  </service>
<services>
```

---

```
// client's binding generation code
var binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport, true) // enable reliable session
{
    OpenTimeout = openCloseTimeout,
    CloseTimeout = openCloseTimeout,
    SendTimeout = sendTimeout,
    ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue // maximum possible value (infinite in app.config)
};

binding.ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue; // maximum possible value (infinite in app.config)

var factory = new ChannelFactory<TChannel>(binding);
return factory.CreateChannel(endpointAddress);
```

So, as you can see, all timeouts are configured to values higher than 10 minutes, and still the channel faults precisely after 10 minutes without any service call. How can I circumvent this? As far as I understood it, reliable sessions are (amongst other things) used exactly for that: keeping channels alive and prevent them from faulting (by sending infrastructure keep alive packets – at least in recent .NET versions without the [aforementioned bug](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/pauloreichert/archive/2007/02/22/WCF-Reliable-Sessions-Puzzle.aspx)).

Comment: I realize this is almost a year old.. but did you set this value on both client and server?

Answer (score 0):

You should have gotten warnings during compile that infinite is no legal value for the timeouts.
The maximun timeout is about 24 days.

Comment: Technically, there is a special config serializer that interprets infinite as TimeSpan.MaxValue, but even so he's overriding the values in code with MaxValue anyways, so your comment isn't quite helpful.